# How to Store form data to the table in another page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to store the form data locally from one page to the another page in a table using javascript?

the javascript code is

```
function addtext()
      {
         var fname = document.myform.first_name.value;
         var lname = document.myform.last_name.value;
         var email = document.myform.email.value;
         document.writeln("Thank you! You have just entered the following:");
         document.writeln("<pre>");
     document.writeln("<td>First Name :</td> " + fname);
         document.writeln("<td>Last Name :</td> " + lname);
         document.writeln("<td>Email Address :</td>  " + email);
    }
```

the HTML part is

```
     <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
        <form name="myform" action="confirm.php" method="get">
        <td>
          <label for="first_name">First Name </label>
          </td>
          <td>
          <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
          <label for="last_name">Last Name </label>
          </td><td><input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
          </td><td><input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
            </td></tr><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="addtext()">
        </form>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RHJW/)! attached. Hope it helps you.

```
var fname = document.myform.first_name.value;
     var lname = document.myform.last_name.value;
     var email = document.myform.email.value;
     document.writeln("Thank you! You have just entered the following:");
     document.writeln("<pre>");
 document.writeln("<td>First Name :</td> " + fname);
     document.writeln("<td>Last Name :</td> " + lname);
     document.writeln("<td>Email Address :</td>  " + email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? Any special reason? not best practice though but if its only user preference not user data then through javascript you can do it through sessionStore or localStorage.

See [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

or if cookie is fine then use jquery cookie

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie